# Why gomonkey.ApplyFunc mocked func in for loop share the same address?

Tags: unit-testing, go, go-testing

I use `gomonkey.ApplyFunc` mock a func in for loop, then call it. Why it returns the same result every time, and the mocked func in loop all points to a same address.

```
func Test2(t *testing.T) {
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        gomonkey.ApplyFunc(env.Loc, func() int {
            tmp := i + 1
            return tmp
        })
        t.Logf("%p, %v", env.Loc, env.Loc())
    }
}

output:
0x8b85c0, 1
0x8b85c0, 1
0x8b85c0, 1
```

Comment: Attempting to monkey patch Go was never safe nor reliable, there's a reason the original gomonkey project was archived. You can file an issue with the developer and see if they can fix it.